# App is crashing while calling interstitialAd.load() method in React-Native

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to place interstitialAd in my project but the **interstitialAd.load();** is crashing the app. My AdMob config is fine ad **Banner ads are working perfectly**.

Used Plugin: @react-native-firebase/admob

Here is the code:

```
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { InterstitialAd, AdEventType, TestIds } from '@react-native-firebase/admob';

export default class InterstitialAdUnit extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    
    showInterstitialAd = () => {
        
        const interstitialAd = InterstitialAd.createForAdRequest(TestIds.INTERSTITIAL);
       
        interstitialAd.onAdEvent((type, error) => {           
            if (type === AdEventType.LOADED) {
                interstitialAd.show();
            }
        });
        
        interstitialAd.load();
    } 
    render() {
        return (
            <Button
                title="Show Interstitial"
                onPress={() => {
                    this.showInterstitialAd();
                }}
            />    
    )}
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dibyendu! I maintain react-native-firebase and I've posted an answer below with details and an official release with the fix :-) Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I maintain react-native-firebase and maybe I can explain why this happened, as well as the fix.

`@react-native-firebase/admob` will not crash if used by itself, with InterstitialAds

However, firebase-android-sdk and the admob just issued a breaking change release (v27 for firebase-android-sdk, v20 for admob) that moves InterstitialAd package names and *if* you have *another* admob dependency where the gradle dependency was specified with a version of `+`, that allows the breaking change version to leak through and break your app.

So pinning the dependency in your `build.gradle` as others have commented will fix you:

```
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.8.0") { force = true; }
```

Full details here: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/5127

react-native-firebase (including the admob module) v11.3.1 is releasing now with contents of this PR to fix things: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/pull/5189

Good luck with your projects

Answer (score 1):

hello my friend i found a solution for you
app/build.gradle
dependencies {
....
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.8.0") { force = true; }
}

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for answering but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the issue? Check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how to format code.

Answer (score 0):

Ei,
I try this solution and seems works for the first test.
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/discussions/5166

Just:
workaround
app/build.gradle

implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.8.0") { force = true; }